# Powershell - add my own steps to Write-progress

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do something with write-progress, however most examples i can find are to complicated. I just need something which i can hardcode in with step 1 to 4 which gives 25% each. To give the user a sense of progression.

```
Write-Progress -Activity 'Title' -Status 'Doing something' -PercentComplete 0
Write-Progress -Activity 'Title' -Status 'Doing something' -PercentComplete 25
```

etc.

do not seem to do anything.

Comment: Are you working directly in the console? Your code works for me. You can add `sleep -seconds 2` to see the progress bar if your code ends too fast

Comment: You have to provide the math for what you are doing. Progress bars need to have a value/values to work with. As for this [owever most examples i can find are to complicated], why are you not using the examples in the help files? This use case is a very common thing. Where did you search? What did you search for?  For example these basic step-thru articles: [A Better Way to Use Write-Progress](https://adamtheautomator.com/building-progress-bar-powershell-scripts/) or
[Using Write-Progress to provide feedback in Powershell](http://wragg.io/using-write-progress-to-provide-feedback-in-powershell)

Comment: @Uuuuuumm this was actually the way i needed it to be. Sleep slows it down enough to prompt the bar. As said before its purely to trick the enduser and not a real reflection of %. Even though i do know where it might hang this way :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write-Progress need values (math/counter stuff) to work from. Start and End, as shown in the examples in the PowerShell Help files.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Write-Progress).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Write-Progress).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
Activity
Status
Id
PercentComplete
SecondsRemaining
CurrentOperation
ParentId
Completed
SourceId
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
#>

Get-help -Name Write-Progress -Examples
# Results

Example 1: Display the progress of a For loop

    for ($I = 1; $I -le 100; $I++ )
    {Write-Progress -Activity "Search in Progress" -Status "$I% Complete:" -PercentComplete $I;}

This command displays the progress of a For loop that counts from 1 to 100. The Write-Progress command includes a status bar heading ("activity"), a status line, and the variable $I (the counter in the For loop), which indicates the relative completeness of the task.


Example 2: Display the progress of nested For loops

    for($I = 1; $I -lt 101; $I++ )
    {Write-Progress -Activity Updating -Status 'Progress->' -PercentComplete $I -CurrentOperation OuterLoop

    for($j = 1; $j -lt 101; $j++ )
    {Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity Updating -Status 'Progress' -PercentComplete $j -CurrentOperation InnerLoop} }
    # Results
    <#
    Updating
    Progress ->
     [ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo] 
    OutsideLoop
    Updating
    Progress
     [oooooooooooooooooo                                                   ] 
    InnerLoop
    #>

This example displays the progress of two nested For loops, each of which is represented by a progress bar.

The Write-Progress command for the second progress bar includes the Id parameter that distinguishes it from the first progress bar. Without the Id parameter, the progress bars would be superimposed on each other instead of being displayed one below the other.

Example 3: Display the progress while searching for a string

    $Events = Get-EventLog -logname system
    $Events | 
    foreach-object -begin {clear-host;$I=0;$out=""} -process {
    if($_.message -like "*bios*") 
    {$out=$out + $_.Message}
    $I = $I+1

    Write-Progress -Activity "Searching Events" -Status "Progress:" -PercentComplete ($I/$Events.count*100)
    } -end {$out}

This command displays the progress of a command to find the string "bios" in the System event log.

In the first line of the command, the Get-EventLog cmdlet gets the events in the System log and stores them in the $Events variable.

In the second line, the events are piped to the ForEach-Object cmdlet. Before processing begins, the Clear-Host cmdlet is used to clear the screen, the $I counter variable is set to zero, and the $out output variable is set to the empty string.

In the third line, which is the Process script block of the ForEach-Object cmdlet, the cmdlet searches the message property of each incoming object for "bios". If the string is found, the message is added to $out. Then, the $I counter variable is incremented to record that another event has been examined.

The fourth line uses the Write-Progress cmdlet with values for the Activity and Status text fields that create the first and second lines of the progress bar heading, respectively. The PercentComplete parameter value is calculated by dividing the number of events that have been processed ($I) by the total number of events retrieved ($Events.count) and then multiplying that result by 100.

In the last line, the End parameter of the ForEach-Object cmdlet is used to display the messages that are stored in the $out variable.

    Get-help -Name Write-Progress -Full
    Get-help -Name Write-Progress -Online
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, this was way more complicated than what i needed but i learned alot!

Comment: No worries, but when using progress bars in any language (PS, Perl, Python, C#, VB.Net, Java, et al, the steps above to indicate stuff is working on stuff is mandatory. You can use sleep, but you'd need to know exactly how long your code will run on individual systems, loop that as well, so still, you know, math, and that is far more difficult/unreliable.